# Nmap program was not found in path. How do I change it?

Tags: python, path, nmap

I'm pretty new to nmap & python so I was wondering if I could get some help with this.

I'm working on mac with Ventura OS

PATH is :

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin:/Users/AaronBrinkley/.nvm/versions/node/v18.13.0/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin:/Users/AaronBrinkley/.nvm/versions/node/v18.13.0/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin
```

Code pasted below

====

```
import nmap

#These variables will be used as ranges for the nmap tool to scan throug
port_min = 0
port_max = 65535

#Uses context manager to open file containing IP addresses
with open('devices_file') as f:
    devices_list = f.read().splitlines()

#User types in range of ports to be scanned
port_range = input("Please enter port range in 'x-x' format ")

nm = nmap.PortScanner()

for device in devices_list:
    print("Now Checking " + device)

    for port in range(port_min, port_max + 1):
        try:
            result = nm.scan(device, str(port))
            port_status = (result['scan'][device]['tcp'][port]['state'])
            print(f"Port {port} is {port_status}")
        except:
            print("Port {port} is not scannable")
```

Comment: Did you install nmap too ?

Comment: What's the error? Please post the full traceback or show the incorrect (and expected) output.

Comment: Yes nmap is installed. The error is basically the same as shown in the thread title, that nmap wasn’t found in the file path. I can paste the full error when I get home.